# Multiple background-attachment values not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass

I have three backgrounds on a scrolling item, all of the multiple values are working properly except for background-attachment in Chrome, it's using scroll for all of them. It's in a Shopify SCSS file, but I've put the same code into CodePen and the bug is still there.

The shadow cover is a white/transparent/white gradient that masks the shadows and should scroll with the container, the shadows should be visible when there is scrollable content in one direction or another.

It's based on this old (2012) post by Lea Verou: http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/

```
.external-list__values {
    padding-left: 5%;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-image:
        /* Shadow cover */
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 5%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 90%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%),
        /* Shadow */
        radial-gradient(grey,rgba(grey,0) 70%),
        radial-gradient(grey,rgba(grey,0) 70%);
    background-attachment:
        /* Shadow cover */
        local,
        /* Shadow */
        scroll,
        scroll;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-position:
        /* Shadow cover */
        0 0,
        /* Shadow */
        left 0 bottom -0.5rem,
        left -0.5rem;
    background-size:
        /* Shadow cover */
        100% 100%,
        /* Shadow */
        100% 1rem,
        100% 1rem;
    li {
        display: block;
        border: 1px dashed darken(grey,20%);
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/l-fischer/pen/RgBbVb

Comment: I am unsure what the expected outcome exactly should be, would you mind clarifying? When I look at your codepen I can see the top and bottom gradient properly displayed when scrolling.

Comment: @PatrikAffentranger What browser do you see it in?

When the container is scrolled to the top, the top shadow should be hidden by the shadow cover gradient, when the container is scrolled to the bottom, the bottom shadow should be hidden by the shadow cover gradient. The visible shadows should indicate when there is more content to scroll to.

Comment: Chrome 61 and Firefox 52 work fine. IE11 it doesn't work. See gif: http://imgur.com/a/Wm17A

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue (62.0 Mac). The shadow should only be displayed when the content is scrolled, the initial padding should hide the shadow.

I've noticed that setting the background attachment to local or scroll works but not if you set them together.

Comment: Same, Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 on Mac and having multiple background-attachment doesn't work... :/ Have you solved in the meanwhile?